# Passing a field name from CFS wordpress plugin through to twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

so I'm very new to PHP and I'm having a little trouble passing a field name through.

I am using custom fields (cfs) and writing in twig for php.

Currently, I just have in my page.twig. The idea being, if an image has been set in Wordpress, the image will display in location set in page.twig.

The field name is `header_image`

```
{%if header_image %}
  {{header_image}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Timber you can easily pass variables from your PHP controller through to your twig view. There are 2 ways to do this:

1) In functions.php you can pass variables globally to the context. The Timber Starter theme has this in it for reference. Your `add_to_content` function, should look like:

```
function add_to_context( $context ) {
    global $cfs;

    $context['header_image'] = $cfs->get('header_image');
```

Think of `$context` as a giant variable that passes through your variables into that actual view.

**Remember:** this makes your variables globally accessible, so you will need to name your CFS id's uniquely. For example `global_phone_number`.

2) To better structure your code, you should pass through your variables to the context, via the controller for that page. This helps ensure that you don't pass around variables that aren't being used.

In your *page.twig* file, you will need to add:

```
$context['header_image'] = $cfs->get('header_image');
```

**Remember:** the $context name is what you use in your twig file, and $cfs name is what you called it in Custom Field Suite.

---

**Lastly:**

The `{% if header_image %}` is good, as this will check whether a variable has been set, and then decided whether to show this block.
However, in CFS, when an image is uploaded, it gives you the option to select *File URL* or *Attachment ID*. This means you will need to handle this result in your twig file.

For example, by choosing *File URL*, you will need to output the `{{header_image}}` as:

`<img src="{{header_image}}" />`

You may also then want to add in the alt attribute based on the images alt text set in Wordpress media library.

Comment: This worked. Your tip on adding the alt was added too:
`$context['image_alt'] = $cfs->get('image_alt');`

And of course adding it wrapped in an img attribute would have helped the first time around :)

Comment: You should be able to set the alt text from within the media library itself. And then get the image attributes. When using a feature image, you can do the following for example:

    {{post.thumbnail._wp_attachment_image_alt}}

You can check the images attributes by turning on debug mode and doing `{{dump(post.thumbnail)}}`. To do this using CFS, you would need to use some Wordpress functions to get this information via the attachment_id, if you set this in CFS instead.